# Php regex for detecting Url URI

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to detect the URI with a possibility of there being get params etc. I just need to get the /val1/val2 regardless if there is any url get params etc. how can I do this in php?

Thanks

```
$regex = '/^\/index.php?(.*)?\?+$/';

// Here are some example URLS
site.com/val1/val2
site.com/index.php/val1/val2
site.com/index.php/val1/val2?get1=val1&get2=val2
```

I want to be able to group the (/val1/val2) no matter what is on the left or right of the uri

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
(?:/[^/?#]+){2}(?=[?#]|$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QiVMfm/1)

**Details**

- `(?:/[^/?#]+){2}` - two repetitions of `/` and then 1+ chars other than `/`, `?` and `#`
- `(?=[?#]|$)` -  a positive lookahead that matches a location immediately followed with `?`, `#` or end of string.

Here is the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=(%3F%3A%2F%5B%5E%2F%3F%23%5D%2B)%7B2%7D(%3F%3D%5B%3F%23%5D%7C%24)):

[image]

[PHP code](https://3v4l.org/UjCRE):

```
$re = '~(?:/[^/?#]+){2}(?=[?#]|$)~';
$str = 'site.com/val1/val2';
if (preg_match($re, $str, $match)) {
   print_r($match[0]);
} // => /val1/val2
```

Comment: just a little bit of escaping and it works: (?:\/[^\/?#]+){2}(?=[?#]|$). Just a question. Would you be able to explain it a little how it works. particularly the "?:" thanks

Comment: @TheMan68 No need to escape `/`, I am using `~` as a regex delimiter. You may see that no escaping is necessary [here](https://regex101.com/r/QiVMfm/1). If you handle the strings individually you may even replace `(?=[?#]|$)` with `(?![^?#])` for better performance.

Comment: Just a side note, I find those regex diagrams to offer little help in what the pattern is actually doing.  I never include them in my answers.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I think they are perfect for short patterns.

Comment: In all  honesty I love regex and fairly handy with it but no where near your understanding unfortunately. Your above explanation doesn't help me much lol as I'm also not good at understanding the chart explanations, but thanks anyway. I'm just waiting for the site to let me mark your answer as the answer

Answer (score 1):

We can first try splitting the string on `?`, to remove the query string, if it exists.  Then, split by `/` path separator and access the last two paths:

```
$url = "site.com/index.php/val1/val2?get1=val1&get2=val2";
$url = explode('?', $url)[0];
$paths = explode('/', $url);

echo "second to last element: " . $paths[count($paths)-2] . "\n";
echo "last element: " . $paths[count($paths)-1];
```

This prints:

```
second to last element: val1
last element: val2
```

This answer avoids using regex entirely, which might result in slightly better performance.